# Manual GestureRecognizer handler in Swift can't have arguments?

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

If I create a GestureRecognizer handler through InterfaceBuilder, I get a method that looks like this:

```
    @IBAction func Tap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      var touchLocation = tap.locationInView(self.view)
      imageView.transform.tx = touchLocation.x
      imageView.transform.ty = touchLocation.y
    }
    //works great
```

If I manually create a GestureRecognizer, I have to create a function with no arguments, like this:

```
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let imageSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
      var iView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), size: imageSize))
      self.view.addSubview(iView)
      let image2 = UIImage(named: "square.png");
      iView.image = image2

      iView.userInteractionEnabled = true
      iView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
      tap.addTarget(self, action: "Tap")
    }

    func Tap(  //why can't I put an argument in here?//  ){
      let tapAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Tap Pressed", message: "You just tapped", preferredStyle: .Alert)
      tapAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Destructive, handler: nil))
      self.presentViewController(tapAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    //works but I've lost access to the sending object
```

If I add an argument to the Tap handler

```
func Tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){

}
//crashes: [tapHandler]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

, it crashes on the Tap. I'd prefer to have a method with access to the sender object. Is there a way to manually create a GestureRecognizer handler and have access to the sender object, the same way you can when you do it through the Interface Builder?

Comment: What happens if you use `sender: UIGestureRecognizer` instead of `UITapGestureRecognizer`, as documentation suggests?

Comment: Thanks Wotjek- I didn't know that, but it is still crashing. Here's the full code for this little View: https://gist.github.com/hairgamiMaster/0c9d1f491b1ffdbe19e5

Comment: The name of the selector with argument is `Tap:` not `Tap`.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you're talking about. Is there a line number in the gist where you see a mistake? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `tap.addTarget(self, action: "Tap:")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selector names are something that Swift inherits from Objective C. In Objective C a selector with single argument has name `selector:` as opposite to just `selector`, which means - no arguments. Change the name of the action in `addTarget` from `Tap` to `Tap:` and it should work then.

Comment: Ahhh.... I get it. Thank you! I could never make it over the Objective-C hump so I wasn't familiar with that concept. Thank you so much!